# Bash :: display one output item per line

Tags: python, bash, command-line

I am running this `python script.py` at terminal which outputs an array of `urls`

```
rem_results = artist.search(name='rem')
rem = rem_results[0]
rem_blogs = rem.blogs
print 'Blogs about rem:', [blog.get('url') for blog in rem_blogs]
```

how can I use a `bash` command in order to output **one item per line**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it within the context of Python, you don't need bash to do what you are doing, just take whatever you are iterating over, and use join on new lines so each value out of your data collection will be separated by a new line in your string:

```
print('Blogs about rem: \n {}'.format('\n'.join(blog.get('url') for blog in rem_blogs)))
```